# How to display menu in view Block in drupal 7

Tags: views, routes

I am creating a website in which i am trying to display the submenu into view block . how can i do this.

menu is Like

A -B-c

D -E-F

I have to display in block view

like This is view block

B C | E F

this have to display in views block  using view.

Comment: Menus created in Drupal become available in block section. So you can show your menu items in block.But still your question is unclear, please be specific if I could help it in any way.

Comment: Hello, Please take some time and provide more information whatever you have tried and whatever issue you have found.

Comment: are you using views 3 or views 2 ?

Comment: You can call a menu block using module_invoke(); ( https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_invoke/7 ) function to add in view.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Views 3 then install [Views Menu Area](https://drupal.org/project/views_menuarea) module, you can show any menu in the views block.

- Enable the module
- Edit your preferred view
- Click "Add" link in header/footer section
- Check "Global: Menu area" and click "Add and configure footer" button
- Enter label and select the menu you wish to list links from
- Click "Apply" button and save the view

[image]

also take a look at [Menu Views](https://drupal.org/project/menu_views) module.